# how to update the older image if i dont want to update the new image in cakephp 3.5

Tags: cakephp-3.0

am working with the cakephp 3.x and facing some problems regarding the upload image,

if am not uploading any image it should take the older image, but its not happening please check, below is my code

```
 public function edit($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('home-layout');
    $detail = $this->Details->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
   if(!empty($this->request->data['img_name']['name'])){
                {
    $this->request->data['img_name'] = $filename;
    }   
    $detail = $this->Details->patchEntity($detail, $this->request- 
   >getData());
              }
   if(!empty($this->request->data['img_name']['name'])){
        $filename = $this->request->data['img_name']['name'];
        $uploadpath ='img/';
        $uploadfile = $uploadpath. $filename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['img_name'] 
          ['tmp_name'],$uploadfile))
        {
         $this->request->data['img_name'] = $filename;
          }   
    $detail = $this->Details->patchEntity($detail, $this->request- 
   >getData());
        }   
        else{
      $detail = $this->Details->patchEntity($detail, $this->request- 
          >getData());
        }


  if ($this->Details->save($detail)) {
         $this->Flash->success(__('The detail has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
          $this->Flash->error(__('The detail could not be saved. Please, try 
     again.'));


   }
  $this->set(compact('detail'));

  }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is the logic just not firing off? If you are getting an error please post the error details.

Comment: am not getting error, am asking how to update the older image if i dont want to change